# codename one transfer data between forms without stateMachine

Tags: codenameone

Hi I am new to codename one and i want to transfer some data between the button clicked on one form and then doing something on the show of the second form.

Any example will be really helpful as i am not able to find anything on the web which is not using the GUI builder.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I just use member variables on the StateMachine class.  E.g. when the button is clicked, store whatever data you need in member variables on the statemachine class.  Then when the second form shows, you can access this data in the on show form callback.

Comment: Also for non-GUI builder examples: https://www.udemy.com/learn-mobile-programming-by-example-with-codename-one/ http://codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-1.html and quite a few others